# HttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope) not working?

Tags: android, ksoap2

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String NAMESPACE = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/";
private static String METHOD_NAME1 = "FahrenheitToCelsius";
private static String METHOD_NAME2 = "CelsiusToFahrenheit";
private static String URL = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?WSDL";
Button btnFar,btnCel,btnClear;
EditText txtFar,txtCel;
int value;
SoapObject result;
```

My code look like below

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  btnFar = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnFar);
  btnCel = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnCel);
  btnClear = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
  txtFar = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtFar);
  txtCel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtCel);
  btnFar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            value = Integer.parseInt(txtFar.getText().toString());
            new soapFahrenheit().execute();
        }
  });               

  btnClear.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
  {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
          txtCel.setText("");
          txtFar.setText("");
    }
  });
}

private class soapFahrenheit extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String> {

  protected void onPreExecute()
  {
     //
      txtCel.setText(value);
  }
  @Override
  protected String doInBackground(String... arg0){

      SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME1);    

        //Use this to add parameters
        request.addProperty("Fahrenheit",value);         

        //Declare the version of the SOAP request
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);          

        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
        envelope.dotNet = true;         

        try {
              HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);                
              androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envelope);
              result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;
        } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }           
        return result.getProperty(0).toString();
  }

  protected void onPostExecute(SoapObject result)
  {
      if(result != null)
      {
          txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());
      }
      else
      {
           Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Response",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
  }
 }
}
```

did i miss anything here? this is killing my days.... please help

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521740/to-use-the-tutorial-in-android-4-0-3-if-had-to-work-with-asynxtasc-but-i-still-d. You need to use a thread or asynctask fro network operations

Comment: Check my answer below. The problem is with the SOAP_ACTION string.

Comment: @Raghunandan i have updated my code but the aplication is getting closed.  Amith, I have changed the SOAP_ACTION thing as well

Comment: Warning for onPostExecute: The method onPostExecute(SoapObject) from the type MainActivity.soapFahrenheit is never used locally

Comment: @Ricky the link posted by me has a working code. follow it will work

Comment: @Raghunandan, thanks. I have followed that only. but its getting stopped without throwing any error. Let me debug it one more time.

Comment: @Ricky what is the error post the stacktrace

Comment: @Ricky   `return result.getProperty(0).toString();`. Then you have    `txtFar.setText(result.getProperty(0).toString());` which should be    `txtFar.setText(result);`

Comment: @Ricky see my updated answer. Am getting the result successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You are making a network communication on the main  UI thread which not allowed Android 4.0+.

So, you need to create a background thread to make the request to the server.

**[AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)** is what you should be using.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the ACTION String

```
http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/tempconvert.asmx?op=FahrenheitToCelsius
```

And xml form

```
   POST /webservices/tempconvert.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: www.w3schools.com
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius" // ACTION

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <soap:Body>
    <FahrenheitToCelsius xmlns="http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/">
      <Fahrenheit>string</Fahrenheit>
    </FahrenheitToCelsius>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

So the ACTION name should like

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION1 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/FahrenheitToCelsius";
```

and

```
private static String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://www.w3schools.com/webservices/CelsiusToFahrenheit";
```

Hope this will solve your problem.

And use dont't do network operation on UI Thread. Use [AsynTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

EDIT:

```
private void doNetwork() {
        SoapObject resultRequestSOAP = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE1, METHOD_NAME1);
        PropertyInfo pi1 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi1.setName("Fahrenheit");
        pi1.setValue(""+value);// Say value= 10
        pi1.setType(PropertyInfo.STRING_CLASS);
        resultRequestSOAP.addProperty(pi1);
        SoapSerializationEnvelope envp = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envp.dotNet = true;
        try {
            envp.setOutputSoapObject(resultRequestSOAP);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
            androidHttpTransport.debug = true;
            androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION1, envp);
            SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envp.bodyIn;
            System.out.println("response"+response.toString() + "  "+response.getProperty(0).toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

    }
```

OUTPUT:

```
 FahrenheitToCelsiusResponse{FahrenheitToCelsiusResult=-12.2222222222222; }
```